# How to separate the real part from the imaginary part?

Tags: complex

```
exp=(E^(-(t/trMz)) (-Gr0 tr+coff1^2 Gr0 tr+Gr0 trMz-coff1^2 Gr0 trMz+2 coff1 Gr0 theta tr trMz wn-2 coff1^2 Gr0 theta tr trMz wn-2 coff1 Gr0 theta trMz^2 wn+2 coff1^2 Gr0 theta trMz^2 wn))/(Gr0Mz trMz (1-2 coff1 theta trMz wn+coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2))+(I Sqrt[1-theta^2] (coff1 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn-2 coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn+coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn-coff1 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn+2 coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn-coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta wn-I coff1 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn+I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn-I coff1 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn+I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn-coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 tr wn^2+coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 tr wn^2+coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 tr wn^2-coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 tr wn^2+2 coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 tr wn^2-2 coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 tr wn^2-2 coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 tr wn^2+2 coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 tr wn^2+2 I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr wn^2-2 I coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr wn^2+2 I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr wn^2-2 I coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr wn^2+coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 trMz wn^2-coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 trMz wn^2-coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 trMz wn^2+coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 trMz wn^2-2 coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 trMz wn^2+2 coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 trMz wn^2+2 coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 trMz wn^2-2 coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta^2 trMz wn^2+2 I coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] trMz wn^2-2 I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] trMz wn^2+2 I coff1^2 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] trMz wn^2-2 I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta Sqrt[1-theta^2] trMz wn^2+coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3-2 coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3+coff1^5 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3-coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3+2 coff1^4 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3-coff1^5 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 theta tr trMz wn^3-I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr trMz wn^3+I coff1^5 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn-I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr trMz wn^3-I coff1^3 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr trMz wn^3+I coff1^5 E^(t (-coff1 theta wn+I coff1 Sqrt[1-theta^2] wn)) Gr0 Sqrt[1-theta^2] tr trMz wn^3))/(2 coff1 Gr0Mz (-1+theta^2) wn (1-2 coff1 theta trMz wn+coff1^2 trMz^2 wn^2))
```

I want to get the "I" coefficient. How to do?

Comment: If all of the variables are real: `exp // Im // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify`

Answer (score 1):

Enter

```
ComplexExpand[exp]
```

and your expression will be evaluated considering all variables as real.

In order to obtain the imaginary part,
`Im[%]`

Comment: If the variables that explicitly appear in the expression are real than this won't help.  After the evaluation of `ComplexExpand`, Mathematica doesn't know anymore that you want the variables to be treated as real. Consider the difference between `Im[ComplexExpand[a + I*b]]` and `ComplexExpand[Im[a + I*b]]`. I *assume* the OP wants the latter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It will work. To answer your comment, you obtain respectively Im[a] + Re[b] and b. They are correct since Im is zero on any real number.

Answer (score 0):

While `Im@ComplexExpand@exp` does give you the imaginary part I also think your expression is wrong, as `Im[exp]` seems to be 0 for any numerical values I set.

First I extracted the symbols from the expression

```
sym = Cases[Level[exp, {-1}] // Union, _Symbol]
```

Then I set some test values:

```
exp /. {coff1 -> 0.2, Gr0 -> 100, Gr0Mz -> 100, theta -> 0.01, 
  tr -> 2, trMz -> 2, wn -> 50}
Plot[{Re[%], Im[%]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The imaginary plot only gives `0` for many test values I tried. Real part has boring decaying harmonic oscillations

I hope some of it helps.